# Queries logged in the 'Slow query log', and 'start transaction' vs 'set autocommit = 0'

Tags: innodb, transaction, mysql-5.7, performance, auto-commit, slow-log

Currently `long_query_time` is set to `5`, and that works.

However, many queries are part of a transaction, and the slow query log only keeps the final `commit;`.

```
# Time: 2018-08-15T15:18:18.205309Z
# User@Host: bijin[bijin] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id: 3274529
# Query_time: 7.510110  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use interferences_db;
SET timestamp=1534329958;
commit;                      # <=== only 'commit' is logged
```

Which is not very informative ( while it's correct, as seen from the db server ).

Is there a way to see the queries up to the `commit`, meaning all queries from the transaction?
(*or at least some part of it allowing to identify the culprit query*)

*~~~ edit ~~~*

The answer from @AmitPatel had me perform some tests using

```
set autocommit = 0
```

instead of

```
start transaction
```

to initiate a transaction and, indeed, with `autocommit = 0` the slow query log has the details of every slow query, even if they're eventually `rollback`ed.

So, in order to log slow queries that are part of a transaction, can I safely replace, in the code,

`start transaction` .... `commit` / `rollback`

with

`set autocommit = 0` .... `commit` or `rollback` and `set autocommit = 1` ?

*( The final `autocommit = 1` is to keep the same behavior in the code, after a transaction is rollbacked or committed )*

Answer (score 2):

Mysql run with autocommit feature , it look like your application code forcefully commit the each DML.

Comment: Please see my edit